# Changing color of particular text in Alert Dialog

Tags: android, xml, android-alertdialog, alert

hi guys i have an xml in that i am having the following :

```
John:How are you?
Mary:I am fine.How about you.
John:what is your plan today?
```

I am fetching these values from xml .Now i need the `John,Mary` text with `BOLD` and in `different color`. and also i need to change the background color of alert window.

this the alert dialog i am using:

```
AlertDialog.Builder bu = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
bu.setMessage(""+((Node) textFNListU.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim().replace("$","\n"));
bu.setCancelable(true);
bu.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.cancel();
                        }
                        });
                bu.create().show();
```

`((Node) textFNListU.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim())` ----this the value i am getting from xml

please help.

Answer (score 11):

You can change color of text like:
for example: string is "John:How are you?" then,

```
builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF0000'><b>John:</b></font>"+"How are you?"))
```

It will give you John: in red color and remaining text in white colored text.You can change that also as per your need.

For customized dialog,you can refer http://blog.androgames.net/10/custom-android-dialog/    - **Not working** : Can't find replacement of this link, please ignore.

Answer (score 0):

make a custom Dialog extends AlertDialog. The System Dialog seems not provide such interface.You can setView to the Dialog, and change the background or other through custom the view.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html in "Creating a Custom Dialog" It use builder.setView(); Also in ApiDemo there exist relative Examples. Hoping useful to you

Answer (score 0):

i think u can use Custom Alert dialog like this....

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application

Comment: thanks but how can make a particular text to be in bold and different color