# Alert dialog with optional text

Tags: android, dialog

how to do alert dialog with optional text. I would like to do so the first 2 words are zeleene colors, blue third, fourth red how to do so? 
Then I was wondering even what it's called dialogue http://prntscr.com/4g8lyk (i want finde google documentation how make it :) )

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CalculatorGUI.this);
builder.setTitle("Choose item");
builder.setCancelable(true);
//builder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        Intent i;




    }
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

alert.show();
```

Comment: you will need custom view for that. check out the setView method of builder.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392063/changing-color-of-particular-text-in-alert-dialog

Comment: pleas give mi link for this :9 http://prntscr.com/4g8lyk